# Networking not going on Ubuntu VMware guest that was copied

Tags: vmware-player

I have a vmware player virtual machine that I created under an Ubuntu system.
When I copy it to another machine to run it there, the guest fails to start it's networking.

I found this link:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=333349

But the file /etc/iftab doesn't exist on Ubuntu 10.10 host.
Besides, won't that alter the host mac address, not the guest?
Seems like an odd fix to me.  Have they got that backwards.  Shouldn't we be editing the vmx file?

I tried this by the way, put the host machine mac address for the adaptor I want into the vmx file but it didn't seem to correct the networking.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very typical (and I must say, annoying!) thing of Ubuntu on VMs

In order to reset this behaviour you need to run the following command

```
rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Once that is done restart your VM and networking should be up and working fine again.

Comment: Thanks! what is persistent-net.rules for anyway?

Comment: hmm, only I have a wifi card + ethernet... so it would seem that removing that file could mean eth0 could be eth1 on the next reboot etc.  It seems you can make persistent names work by bus number too.  by the way, why would this break vmware?

Comment: This breaks because this file is created the first time the machine boots up, it sticks the MAC address to the interface, which should be unmutable in all cases... except when you move a VM from one machine to another, happened to me before as well :/